# Regex first ends with jpg|jpeg|gif|png

Tags: python, regex

So I have this regex:

```
https?://[^/\s]+/\S+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

And am using it on this text:

```
[url=http://www.gameoverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Nintendo-World-Championship-2015-News-1024x576.jpg]http://www.gameoverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Nintendo-World-Championship-2015-News-1024x576.jpg[/url]

En tråd för oss som sitter uppe i natt och vill diskutera vad som händer i tävlingen. 

Det ska tydligen spelas oannonserade spel så det här ska bli kul :D 

Länk till sändningen:
[url=http://www.gonintendo.com/stories/235824-nintendo-world-championships-2015-treehouse-live-pre-show-full]http://www.gonintendo.com/stories/235824-nintendo-world-championships-2015-treehouse-live-pre-show-full[/url]
```

The problem is that it takes everything between http:// and .jpg. So in this case I get a wrong url.

It currently matches

```
http://www.gameoverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Nintendo-World-Championship-2015-News-1024x576.jpg]http://www.gameoverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Nintendo-World-Championship-2015-News-1024x576.jpg
```

but i want it to match

```
http://www.gameoverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Nintendo-World-Championship-2015-News-1024x576.jpg
```

Can anyone provide a way to do this?

Example: https://regex101.com/r/jE7oN8/1

Comment: Is this a question ?

Comment: So, what should the regex match? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your `[^/\s]+` to be lazy, rather than greedy, so it only matches up to the first `.`. Add a `?` to the end.

Note: `[^\s]` is every character that isn't whitespace, and `/` is not whitespace, so you can change it to just `[^\s]`. In addition, there's a shortcut for that in most languages: `\S` (no brackets!). With this change, your regex becomes:

```
https?://\S+?/\S+?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

and it's exactly equivalent. Also, you really don't need to separate two sections with a slash -- just do

```
https?://\S+?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

and [it works the same](https://regex101.com/r/gK6tG1/1).